# rails 4 mass assignment error with protected_attributes gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a user profile sub module to a user module but having some problems.

Routes:

```
resources :users do
    resources :userprofiles
end
```

userprofiles_controller.rb:

```
class UserprofilesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @user.UserProfile ||= UserProfile.new
    @userprofile = @user.UserProfile
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    @user.UserProfile ||= UserProfile.new
    @userprofile = @user.UserProfile
      if @userprofile.update_attributes(:userprofile => params[:userprofile])
        redirect_to @user
        flash[:notice] = "Changes saved."
      else
        render 'edit'
        flash[:notice] = "Error."
      end
  end
end
```

user_profile.rb:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :summary
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes for UserProfile: userprofile
```

Line:

```
if @userprofile.update_attributes(:userprofile => params[:userprofile])
```

**EDIT**

Form:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @userprofile], url: user_userprofile_path(@user, @userprofile)) do |form| %>


    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>

    <%= form.label :last_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name %>


    <%=  form.label :summary %>
    <%=  form.text_area :summary %>

    <%= form.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-block btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Table:

```
  create_table "user_profiles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.text     "summary"
    t.integer  "user_id",    null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: I think you're trying to pass nested attributes for UserProfile, aren't you?

Comment: I'm not sure (new to RoR), the routes are nested.

Comment: Does the form have any userprofile attributes besides first_name, last_name, and summary?

Comment: Edited the OP for more info. Just user_id and time-stamps. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want

```
@userprofile.update_attributes(params[:userprofile])
```

That's a hash with keys `:first_name`, `:last_name`, and `:summary`, which are allowed attributes. When you try to update `:userprofile => params[:userprofile]`, the model checks to see if the key `:userprofile` is allowed - and it isn't.

Comment: Your solution fixed the bug but what I find now is that even though the form is submitted, the new information is not posted.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  The issue is that you still have attr_accessible in your model controller.  Since you don't need them anymore with Rails 4 remove them, add your strong parameters to the controller, and you'll be able to mass-assign without issue.